# Unable to install ios and android requirements in windows-10

Tags: nativescript-angular

I am running below command using CMD(as administrator) provided in to [document](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/quick-setup#step-2-install-ios-and-android-requirements) (In Full setup section - Step-2),

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass  -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"
```

but getting below exception,

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure      channel."
At line:1 char:1
```

After doing some google search, I found that I need to change the security protocol to Tls1.2, so tried to fire same command using Windows PowerShell(as administrator) after adding the protocal Tls1.2,

First command to add Tls1.2,

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

second same command which I ran on CMD,

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass  -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"
```

but by using PowerShell, I got below,
[image]

I would appreciate if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

After you set the SecurityProtocolType in Powershell, simply execute this in Powershell as well:

```
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))
```